# What is the correct hook for Ember Route to check authorization?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

In an Ember.js application, you can use various hooks to check authorization. There are *beforeModel*, *willTransition*, *redirect* hooks on route. also the same events applies on Router.

I'm developing authorization infrastructure for a project. All the route's are written by developers. But an abstract-route (which is extended by all routes) is my code.

1. If I implement *beforeModal* or *redirect* hook in an abstract-route, when a developer writes his own beforeModal methods, my hook will be overwritten.
2. If I implement *willTransition*, checking code will be laid on a route that starts transition. [From the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/), it seems that willTransition is applicable when leaving the route.
3. Is it a correct way to handle Router's events?

So what is the correct way to check authorization and abort/prevent transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice plugin for authorization, [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth), no need to re-invent the wheel.

If you insist to develop your own solution, you will need to: 1) Modify an adapter for ember data (to include auth headers in all queries) 2) Implement error handling on application route (handle 401 error) 3) (optional) Create a mixin for routes to check authorization on client side. beforeModel is a good place for this check, I guess. If developer will need to implement their own beforeModel hook, they just need to put this line in the beginning: `this._super(...arguments);`

Comment: I've looked it but we are not using ember-data. We main need is detailed roles and privileges to implement route's authorization check.

Comment: @ykaragol You may do it in `beforeModel`, but all checks must be duplicated on backend, because front can be easy enough hacked.

Comment: Yes, we do so, we do double check every thing. Data boundaries, business rules, privileges... Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @ykaragol Ember Simple Auth doesn't require you to use Ember Data at all. There is a mixin that will automatically inject an authorization header into all Ember Data requests but you don't have to use thtat of course.

Comment: All I need is to check *this._super(...arguments);* statement is used. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `beforeModel`. [Example from ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/addon/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin.js#L55):

```
beforeModel(transition) {
  if (!this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
    transition.abort();
    this.transitionTo(Configuration.authenticationRoute);
  } else {
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
}
```

As Gennady suggests, you should look into ember-simple-auth since it does exactly what you want.